# Implement whole R script contains functions into shiny

Tags: r, function, shiny, shiny-server

I have a complex R script which contains many  new declared functions. These functions are able to check and clear given file under some requirements.
I want to prepare a simple user interface, where people without any knowledge about R will be able to upload source file, choose some options, and download analysed file without looking into a code.

I prepared a simple shiny app which contains my archival R code in the past, however each time when I want to perform some calculations, I had to use `reactive()` and add `()` after each variable.

This time, script is too complex to adjust it to `reactive()` form.
Is there any way to implement whole R script with avoid this?

Comment: There may be better, native, ways of implementing what you're after, but you can always call `system("Rscript yourscript.R")` to run the analysis.

Comment: Can I prepare simple shiny app to get settings from user, then launch R script in way that you metioned and at the end send the result file again to shiny app user ?